# How to change the icon/logo of artfacts, library when deploy to maven central?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-central

[image: example]

I saw in first version of maven pom structure, you can do that, direct under project element or inside organization element but in the latest version its not possible.

Can anyone point in the right direction or to some documentation?